# Questions on WCF

Tags: wcf

I am learning WCF,one of the benefits of WCF is that you can use WCF even the client and service are not in the same network.Can anyone explain why?
Why using normal asp.net services, .NET remoting or Windows enterprise service client and service have to be in the same network?

Another question is that does the client needs to have a service contract interface and data contract? I assume not ,but how the client understand the type returned from the WCF services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you read that a benefit of WCF is that it allows the client and server to be on different networks. They can already be on different networks using .NET Remoting or DCOM (Enterprise Services).

The client does need to know the service contract and any other contracts required in order to use the service. This can be provided through WSDL or the Metadata Exchange Protocol (mex). If using .NET on both sides, then it is possible to share the contract assemblies, but this introduces a coupling between client and service.

Comment: Hey I am watching some appdev WCF services training,the benefit has been said there.That's why I am confused and ask the questions here.I can not figure out why the network location matters.

Comment: The network location does not matter. Can you post a link to the training where this is said?

Comment: It is inside the video itself there is no link I can point to it.I can find any other places said so and I think it must be a mistake to it.Thansk for your answers.

Comment: No, I meant a link to the video.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Reflecting More comments

A [primer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) on WCF (such as [What Is Windows Communication Foundation?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx)) is a good place to start. WCF can use SOAP to implement the contracts way down deep. WCF also uses a variety of communication facilities within windows (and any custom ones you want to create) so talking across machines is built in.

The very essence of contract (IMO) implies that this is present on both sides of the communication. In a pure .net cases I've usually put the [contract definitions](http://blogs.conchango.com/simonevans/archive/2007/04/22/WCF-Contract-Design-Guidelines.aspx) in separate assemblies and share them. In other places I've used [WSDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) to be the main contract definition so that the client and service share definitions.

Edit: Answering comments

You can knock up simple examples of communication in WCF easilyy (provided you know the basics of comms on windows including firewalls etc). However doing something custom is not easy but there are many many resources on the web and books to help you get there.

The books i used:

- [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-WCF-Services-Juval-Lowy/dp/0596526997](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526997)
- [http://www.amazon.com/Essential-Windows-Communication-Foundation-WCF/dp/0321440064/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_c](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321440064)
- [http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Windows-Communication-Foundation-Developer/dp/0735623066/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1252111759&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623066)

Another question on SO with a set of resources is "[WCF for the Totally Clueless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296040/wcf-for-the-totally-clueless)"

Comment: Hey mate , I can make the wcf working and reading the books.Here are just the questions I come across.I do not want to read the whole books to find the answers if you can give me a brief explanation ,it would be much easier for me.

Comment: -1: WCF does not use SOAP all the time. It's independent of message format. For example, netMsmqBinding doesn't use SOAP, nor do the web* bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Previous Microsoft technologies were designed for some specific needs in particular environment. For example ASMX Web Services were designed to send and receive messages using SOAP over Http only. .NET Remoting specific to Microsoft environment, no interoperability. But WCF is designed to send and receive messages using any format (SOAP as default) over any transport protocol i.e. HTTP, TCP, NamedPipes, MSMQ etc.

And your second question "but how the client understand the type returned from the WCF services?"
Its through proxy, client interacts with proxy which contains all the types etc.

You can find a good [concepts and questions here](http://wcfanswers.blogspot.com/2012/06/wcf-top-10-interview-questions.html) for understanding WCF core concepts.